# Unable to Install php-pgsql (Virtual) Module in WordPress:8.2 Docker Container

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, installation, php-pgsql

It is not possible for me to install the php-pgsql (virtual) module in a  cointainer based on the official image  wordpress:8.2

In theory, as the container runs a debian12 bookworm code shouldn't be any problem.
The installation **should be as trivial as** run this code

`root@a1cc7e9211ce:/var/www/html# apt update && apt install php8.2-pgsql`

but it fails

```bash
root@a1cc7e9211ce:/var/www/html# apt install php8.2-pgsql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package php8.2-pgsql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php8.2-pgsql' has no installation candidate
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
```

The surprising fact is that the package is present

```
root@a1cc7e9211ce:/var/www/html# apt search php8.2-pgsql
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
php8.2-pgsql/bookworm 8.2.15-1+0~20240120.39+debian12~1.gbp56f296 amd64
 (none)
```

I want to clarify that the apt install php8.2-pgsql command fails despite the package being present in the repository.

So my question is:

- is there any limitation in the version of the php used in the image of wordpress:8.2 I'm using?
  why couldn't  and how could I install the php-pgsql module in the container?
- does exist a version of wordpress image with the php-pgsql module already installed?

And (as a workaround):
I use a second container (with wp_CLI) to install wordpress in the first container. Can I manually download the wp code in the first container (so I would have a standard Debian12 installation) and then install the wp using a wp_cli as done now?

As you can imagine, manually downloading the WordPress code and installing it with WP-CLI would be a workaround, but it would require more effort than simply installing the php-pgsql module. So I would prefer just to install the module...

I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM wordpress:php8.2

RUN apt update -q && \
    apt install -q -y libpq-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql pgsql
```

Launch a container and check what modules installed via the PHP CLI:

[image]

Comment: **Thank you very** much for your answer. It looks like that this is a good way to install the php-pgsql module.

I was not aware of the **existence of docker-php-ext-install** command (that, as far as I have understood, is a script that simplifies the installation of PHP extensions inside Docker containers).


I'm testing your solution right now :-) 
(then I'll select yours as the correct answer)